# Hypothesis testing - When to subtract one during type I and type II testing?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I'm currently studying statistics and I'm reviewing notes I took during a class last week. However, there's something I'm confused about.
My professor subtracted 1 from the "successes" and I can't seem to figure out why.
Essentially, the scenario was like this:

Someone flipped a coin 16 times.

$$H_0:p=0.5\text{ v.s. }H_a:p=0.55$$

Test 1: Reject $p = 0.50$ if 10 or more heads are observed out of 16.

$\text{Pr}(X \ge  10 \text{ when } p= 0.5)$ where X is a binomial with $n = 16$ and $p = 0.50$.

This is the part I don't understand. When using R, he did the following:

```
1 - pbinom(9, 16, 0.5)
```

Where did the 9 come from? Why did he subtract 1 from the initial 10 tosses? If I was in a scenario where I had:

$$\text{Pr}(X \le 15 \text{ when } p = 0.50)$$

Would I still subtract 1? Would the R solution be `pbinom(15, 16, 0.50)` or `pbinom(14, 16, 0.50)`? How do we decide when to subtract 1 like this?

( Sorry if my formatting is bad! I've never posted math equations like this to these forums and I can't seem to figure it out)

Comment: $\mathbb P(X\ge 10)=1-\mathbb P(0\le X\le 9)=$ `1 - pbinom(9, 16, 0.5)`

Comment: @5201314 In the case of something like Pr(X ≤ 15), does this still apply? No, right?

Comment: $\mathbb P(X\le 15)$ is simply `pbinom(15, 16, 0.50)`.

Comment: Deleting earlier draft of Answer. Brief connectivity crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X \ge 10) = 1 - P(X \le 9) = 0.2272491.$ In R, `pbinom` is a binomial CDF and `dbinom` a binomial PDF.

For $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=16,p=.5)$ here are three ways to find $P(X \ge 10)$ in R.
The last, and most direct method, subtracting the CDF, is the one shown in class.

```
sum(dbinom(10:16, 16, .5))
[1] 0.2272491
1 - sum(dbinom(0:9, 16, .5))
[1] 0.2272491
1 - pbinom(9, 16, .5)
[1] 0.2272491

x = 0:16;  PDF = dbinom(x, 16, .5)
plot(x, PDF, type="h", lwd=2, main="PDF of BINOM(16, .5)")
 abline(v=0, col="green2");  abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 9.5, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

The desired probability is the sum of the heights of the bars to the
right of the dotted red line.